# C++, reading text from txt file and append to textbox or append text from edit box to textbox

Tags: c++

For a school assignment I have to finish up a game. I have it almost completed, but the last assignment is giving me a hard time.

At the moment I have figured out how to obtain the text (name) from the edit box when the user has a high score.

This is done with:

```
GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, &Tsaved, 20);//Get text from edit box
```

I am also able to append it to a message box with this:

```
MessageBox(hDlg, &Tsaved, buff, IDOK == nId);//write text from edit box to message box
```

My thought process and process of code is this:

At the moment I am writing my obtained text to a text file, because I was not able to directly append the obtained text to the text box. With this I'm am able to write something in the file.

I know that `Tsaved` is a `TCHAR` and only 2 bytes, but in order to write it to a file which uses a string I have to cast/convert it to string. With this I am only to write the first letter of obtain text to the file.

Example: 
Editbox input :  "Don"
Message box output: "Don"
Text file output: "D"

This is how I have done the casting/converting:

```
TCHAR Ts = Tsaved;
stringstream ss;
string s;
char c = Ts;
ss << c;
ss >> s;
```

And this is how I write it to the file:

```
std::ofstream inputfile("filename.txt");
if (!inputfile)
{
    std::cerr << "Error writing to ..." << std::endl;
}
else
{
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(Tsaved)-1; x++)
    {
        int a = sizeof(Ts);
        //inputfile << sizeof(Tsaved) / sizeof(TCHAR) << endl;
        inputfile << s << endl;
        //inputfile << a << endl;
    }
}
```

How am I able to write the full content of the obtained editbox to the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that `Tsaved` only has enough space to contain one character. You need to allocate enough memory to hold the entire context of the text box. You can do this by calling [GetWindowTextLength()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetWindowText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
HWND hEditBox = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
int len = GetWindowTextLength(hEditBox);

TCHAR* text = new TCHAR[len+1]; // need +1 to account for  trailing nullptr
GetWindowText(hEditBox, text, len);
```

`text` should now contain the full text of the editbox. You can now write that to the file:

```
std::ofstream inputfile("filename.txt");
inputFile << text;
```

Since `text` was allocated using `new[]`, you will need to delete it as well:

```
delete[] text;
```

Secondly, I don't know if your program is compiled as Unicode or not, but if it is `TCHAR` will be defined as `wchar_t` instead of `char`. Since it can contain non-ASCII characters, you should use `std::wofstream` instead of `std::ofstream`. The two classes have the same API, but the latter can handle all Unicode characters.

Finally, I don't know what version of Visual Studio you are using, but if it is a recent one you can replace the `new[]` and `delete[]` with a [unique_ptr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601(v=vs.140).aspx) (which will automatically delete the allocated memory so you don't have to remember to do so):

```
std::unique_ptr<TCHAR[]> text = std::make_unique<TCHAR[]>(len + 1);
GetWindowText(hEditBox, text.get(), len);

inputFile << text.get();
```

Comment: Thanks you very ,much i will try it in a second.  i am using visual studio 2015     ... one more question , you said it only has space to for one charachter , and thats correct because i have noticed that. but how is it possible that the message box is able to get the full obtained text ?

Comment: @D-Antonio Since you said you have room for 20 characters when calling `GetDlgItemText()`, it copied all 20 characters for you. The extra 19 characters were getting written to whatever was in memory after the 1 character you had space for, so that memory was corrupted. Basically you got lucky that nothing important was overwritten.